# Classes. Can someone tell me if I did this exercise correctly?

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to create a Temperature class based on these instructions:

Consider a class called Temperature. This class consists of a double called degrees and a string called type. This class has a default constructor. The class also has a constructor taking arguments that only takes an argument for the degrees variable. It has an accessor called get_temperature() that returns a double. It has an overloaded bool operator < that takes as an argument another Temperature object T. It also has a mutator member function called set_type that takes as an argument a string and returns nothing. Write the declaration for the class Temperature. Use the const keyword when appropriate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Temperature {
public:
    Temperature (double degrees_x){
        double degrees = degrees_x;
    }
    void set_type(string type_x){
        string type = type_x;}
        double get_temperature() const;
    bool operator < (Temperature T) const;
private:
    double degrees;
    string type;


};
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: `double degrees =...` does not belong in that constructor. That declares a local variable that hides the member variable `degrees`. It should simply be `degrees = ...`, and ideally, it should be in a member initialization list. The same goes for `type` in `set_type`.

Comment: you could also replace the argument `Temperature T` with `const Temperature &T` at your `< operator` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So would it look something like this?

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Temperature {
public:
    Temperature(){degrees = 0.0; type = "";};
    Temperature (double degrees_x){
        degrees = degrees_x;
    }
    void set_type(string type_x){
        type = type_x;}
        double get_temperature() const;
    bool operator < (Temperature T) const;
private:
    double degrees;
    string type;
        
    
};

Comment: 1.  This is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/
2.  const double degrees;   - since your degrees value doesn't change after your constructor.

Comment: @UKMonkey No. Because the code isn't working as it should.

Comment: @Monrelle `double degrees = degrees_x;` in the constructor body and `string type = type_x;` shadow your member variables. To address these omit the type specifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Temperature {
    //no need to declare private members as private, the default is private
    double degrees;
    string type;
public:
    Temperature (double degrees_x){
        degrees = degrees_x;
    }
    //when setting the type, using 'set_type(string type_x) is inefficient, as type_x will be copied if given an l-value, and then copied again into 'type'
    //getting 'type_x' as const& will make sure you make a single copy, which is in 'string type = type_x' when the copy assigment of the class 'string' is called
    void set_type(const string& type_x){
        string type = type_x;
    }
    double get_temperature() const;
    //the most reasonable thing to do, as already mentioned, is passing T as const&, since you probably won't modify the second operand when checking if T1<T2
    bool operator < (const Temperature &T) const;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things which could/should be corrected.

The operator< argument could be const reference

```
bool operator < (const Temperature& T) const;
```

Avoid the "using namespace" in header files - pollutes the global namespace

The lines:

```
double degrees = degrees_x;
string type = type_x;
```

define a local variable which you assing to the values from arguments passed to the constructor and set_type method. Hence, the object member fields are not initialized as you expect them to.
For the constructor you could simply put

```
Temperature (double degrees_x) : degrees(degrees_x), type(""){}
```

as for set_type method:

```
type = type_x;
```

Also the method could take a const& argument instead a string value

Additionally two of the includes (time.h and iostream) seems unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version with some inline comments about the changes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Temperature {
public:
    Temperature (double degrees_x) : 
      degrees(degrees_x)      // this sets the value of the object variable
                              // it means that we can use const double degrees later
    {}

    // Note here that the signature has changed to be a const & 
    void set_type(const string& type_x) {
        type = type_x;         //sets the object variable type to the value.
        // one could alternatively use the non-const, and then std::move.

        //string type = type_x;  but this creates a local variable, and assigns the value... not what you want.
    }

    // good uses of const here for function declarations.
    double get_temperature() const;
    bool operator < (const Temperature& t) const; // but this should be const & argument, since you shouldn't change it
    // as a style note, T is a common name for template parameters, so I'd suggest naming it t rather than T
private:
    const double degrees;  // this never changes after the constructor
    string type;           // this however can, so mustn't be const
};
```